# Pandas dataframe with two columns but only shows one in shape function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The original dataframe has a column called release_year and a column called rating, and each year might include several ratings. I tried to calculate the average rating of each year and return a two column dataframe.

```
df = df.groupby('release_year')['rating'].mean()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

The result looks like a two column datafrme, but when I use shape funtion, it shows there's one only.

```
new_df.shape
>>>(86, 1)
```

The dataframe I get

```
rating
release_year    
1921    8.200000
1924    8.100000
1925    8.100000
1926    8.100000
1927    8.200000
... ...
2018    8.300000
2019    8.233333
2020    8.200000
2021    8.100000
2022    8.150000
```

Comment: because release_year is index. You can use **reset_index()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do the groupby , the grouped column becomes INDEX.

example:

df:

| INDEX | COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ITEM1 | ITEM2 |

`df.groupby('col1')`:

| COL1(NOW INDEX) | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | ITEM2 |

you can use `df.reset_index()` to get indexes and change it to a column.